# Are the phrases "I've had an experience" and "I'm experienced" equivalent?

Tags: phrases

Is there any difference between

> I've had an experience in something

and

> I'm experienced in something

?

Comment: Yes, they mean completely different things. Have you consulted any dictionaries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SHORT VERSION:**

Only if you change the first statement to

> I ***have experience*** in something

does it have the same meaning as the second statement.

**LONG VERSION:**

Make sure you understand the difference between (2) and (3) in the treatment of the **noun** [here](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/experience):

> 2.
>
> a. Active participation in events or activities, leading to the accumulation of knowledge or skill . . .
>
> b. The knowledge or skill so derived.
>
> 3.
>
> a. An event or a series of events participated in or lived through.

as well as the difference between the **adjective** *[experienced](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/experienced)*:

> 1. Having had experience in an activity or in life in general: *a highly experienced traveler.*
> 2. Skilled or knowledgeable as the result of active participation or practice: *consulted an experienced investment counselor.*

and the past tense of the **verb**, *experience(d)* (below the noun entries linked above):

> To participate in personally; undergo; *experience a great adventure; experienced loneliness*

Now to address your examples:

> "I've had ***an*** experience ***in*** something"

is unusual phrasing.  It looks like an awkward cross between "I had an experience" (noun, 3) and "I have experience with _____" (noun, 2).

Normally, "***an*** experience" specifies one event or occasion, as in definition 3a above.  This is singular and therefore distinct from the idea of *ongoing* experience.

But experience "***in something***" suggests practical exposure, as in definition 2a.

> "I'm experienced in something"

This is much clearer than your previous phrase, because the **adjective** *experienced* only corresponds to Definition 2 of the **noun**; there is no equivalent adjective "experienced" that corresponds to the noun's Definition 3.

Comment: Also note that the answer required interpreting your use of "something".  I was guessing that using "in something" both times was meant to indicate a practical subject like a profession, craft, trade, or hobby.  That's what made "I've had an experience in something" look odd.  However, if for that "something" we substituted "this room", or "water", or "Michigan", or "mid-air" - anything/anywhere else *in* which you could be physically located while you "had an experience", the phrasing would fit quite comfortably.

Answer (score 0):

An experience is a noun

To be experienced is an adjective

"I'm very experienced" implies that you've had many experiences, however people use it to say that you've done it for a long time and you're very good at it.